# how to make flash swf fluid size as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on facebook game and I want my game have fluid width. What is best practice to achive it ?

Shoul I only use special way of embeding or I need make changes in as3 code as well ?

I tryed google for it but I was not sucesfull.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3fluidresize/

How does i google?

Comment: there is not explained how can I make it resizable when it is embeded in webpage!

Comment: @Riddlah When embedding the swf, you'll also need to set the width and height to a certain percentage (normally 100%)

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html

the swf gets planted in a page, the containing element needs to have fluid height and width. The swf will update based on the containing element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you need to embed your swf with `width=100%` for width and `height=100%` for height.

Your SWF file will assume the stageWidth/stageHeight to be the size of the container it's in. Then, to trace if the window is resized, use following listener:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, YOUR_HANDLER);
```